# How can I send raw JSON Data in PUT method In Guzzle POST Body?

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, guzzle

This should be soo simple but I have spent hours searching for the answer and am truly stuck. I am building a basic Laravel application and am using Guzzle to replace the CURL request I am making at the moment.

actually I want to send data as JSON in request Body , in PUT method ,using Guzzel PHP client. please anyone help me how can i send. 
please share complete code , i am new to using it.

Comment: Provide the sample code for what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

According to the doc of guzzle

`$response = $client->request('PUT', '/put', ['json' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);`

What version of guzzle do you have and what did you try ?